# JavaFX and IntelliJ -- Table Values Won't Populate?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Doing my homework, and trying to get some values to spit out onto a table in IntelliJ right now. I'm following a webinar series, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I try to add a part to the system, but I get an error that "non-static method addPart(classes.Part) cannot be referenced from a static context." Along with three other errors around the same area in my MainApplication.java file.

```
package project.wfc482project;

import classes.InHouse;
import classes.Outsourced;
import classes.Part;
import classes.Inventory;
import classes.Product;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainApplication.class.getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("C482 Inventory Management System");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Sample values, Parts, and Products


        InHouse inhouse1 = new InHouse(1, "Tire", 10.99, 10, 0, 20, 125);
        InHouse inhouse2 = new InHouse(2, "Strut", 12.99, 27, 0, 30, 124);
        Outsourced outsourced1 = new Outsourced(3, "Tubing", 7.50, 5, 0, 15, "Super Parts");
        Outsourced outsourced2 = new Outsourced(5, "Lens", 3.50, 22, 0, 25, "Auto Glass");




        Inventory.addPart(inhouse1);
        Inventory.addPart(inhouse2);
        Inventory.addPart(outsourced1);
        Inventory.addPart(outsourced2);

        launch();

        // Call static members





    }
}
```

And here's the Inventory.java page that I am trying to pull from, which pulls from a Parts.java page that I'll throw up here in a sec...

```
package classes;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Inventory {

    private static int partId = 0;


    private static int productId = 0;


    private static ObservableList<Part> allParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    private static ObservableList<Product> allProducts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public static ObservableList<Part> getAllParts() {
        return allParts;
    }





    public ObservableList<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return allProducts;
    }


    public void addPart(Part newPart) {
        allParts.add(newPart);
    }


    public void addProduct(Product newProduct) {
        allProducts.add(newProduct);
    }


    public static int getNewPartId() {
        return ++partId;
    }

    public static int getNewProductId() {
        return ++productId;
    }


    public Part lookupPart(int partId) {
        Part partFound = null;

        for (Part part : allParts) {
            if (part.getId() == partId) {
                partFound = part;
            }
        }

        return partFound;
    }


    public ObservableList<Part> lookupPart(String partName) {
        ObservableList<Part> partsFound = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (Part part : allParts) {
            if (part.getName().equals(partName)) {
                partsFound.add(part);
            }
        }

        return partsFound;
    }


    public Product lookupProduct(int productId) {
        Product productFound = null;

        for (Product product : allProducts) {
            if (product.getId() == productId) {
                productFound = product;
            }
        }

        return productFound;
    }


    public ObservableList<Product> lookupProduct(String productName) {
        ObservableList<Product> productsFound = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (Product product : allProducts) {
            if (product.getName().equals(productName)) {
                productsFound.add(product);
            }
        }

        return productsFound;
    }


    public void updatePart(int index, Part selectedPart) {

        allParts.set(index, selectedPart);
    }


    public void updateProduct(int index, Product selectedProduct) {

        allProducts.set(index, selectedProduct);
    }


    public boolean deletePart(Part selectedPart) {
        if (allParts.contains(selectedPart)) {
            allParts.remove(selectedPart);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public boolean deleteProduct(Product selectedProduct) {
        if (allProducts.contains(selectedProduct)) {
            allProducts.remove(selectedProduct);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Part Class:

```
package classes;

public abstract class Part {

    // Declare fields
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int stock;
    private int min;
    private int max;

    // Declare Constructor

    public Part(int id, String name, double price, int stock, int min, int max) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Part() {

    }


    // Setters and Getters
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @param price the price to set
     */
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * @return the stock
     */
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    /**
     * @param stock the stock to set
     */
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    /**
     * @return the min
     */
    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    /**
     * @param min the min to set
     */
    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    /**
     * @return the max
     */
    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    /**
     * @param max the max to set
     */
    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

}
```

And the InHouse class:

```
package classes;


public class InHouse extends Part{

    private int machineId;


    public InHouse(int id, String name, double price, int stock, int min, int max, int machineId) {
        super(id, name, price, stock, min, max);
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }

    public int getMachineId() {
        return machineId;
    }

    public void setMachineId(int machineId) {
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }
}
```

I've tried looking up answers to this on here and Reddit, but I'm having a hard time making sense of it all.

I understand that I can't make a part for an abstract class, although that's what the webinar tells me to do (it's more likely that that's what I'm interpreting that as, but I'm turned around and not understanding it).

Comment: Please disregard the apostrophes and <html>/</html> placed around everything -- tried following instructions on posting the code properly, got fork stuck in outlet instead lol

Comment: I fixed the formatting, you can see the differences in the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74605742/revisions).  All you need to do is indent code four spaces with blank lines before and after.  The `{}` tool on the editing toolbar does the same thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the method `Inventory.addPart()` to a static method. Change this:

```java
    public void addPart(Part newPart) {
        allParts.add(newPart);
    }
```

to this

```java
    public static void addPart(Part newPart) {
        allParts.add(newPart);
    }
```

Comment: Probably a better idea is to get rid of all static things from the Inventory class, create a single instance of the inventory class and use a reference, searches for when to use the static keyword in Java will provide information on why this is advisable for this instance.